# Typing sqlplus / as sysdba gives nothing

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

[image: Screenshot]

SQLPLUS command gives no output while trying to log in as sysdba.

```
sqlplus / as sysdba
```

Comment: Could you please explain in detail?

Comment: sqlplus sys@pdb18c/password as sysdba

Comment: Maybe you have a shell script or alias that is masking it; assuming you are in the `bin` directory in your ORACLE_HOME, what does `./sqlplus` do? If that also does nothing, what is the file size, and have you recently installed or patched - possibly a failure left an executable with zero size, for instance.